# Find date difference in php?

Tags: php, date, datediff

Is there anyway to find the date difference in php?  I have the input of from date 2003-10-17 and todate 2004-03-24.  I need the results how many days is there within these two days.  Say if 224 days, i need the output in days only.

I find the solution through mysql but i need in php.  Anyone help me, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the parse timestamp feature to convert dates to timestamps, subtract the timestamps, and then convert the resulting timestamp (seconds) to days:

```
floor((strtotime("2004-03-24") - strtotime("2003-10-17"))/86400);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$start = new DateTime( '2003-10-17' );
$end   = new DateTime( '2004-03-24' );
$diff  = $start->diff( $end );

echo $diff->format( '%d days' );
```

...should do it.

For reference see [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php).

Mind you though, this is only available as of PHP 5.3.

Comment: I got this type of error :

Fatal error: Class 'DateTime' not found

Comment: @Karthik: yes, sorry... I should have mentioned it's only available as of PHP 5.3.

Comment: I would use DateTime::createFromFormat('!Y-m-d', '2003-10-17') mainly because I don't like depending on strtotime magic functionality. I always feel like it will get the month and day mixed up, even though it seems to work properly with yyyy-mm-dd format.

Answer (score 0):

Example is as below:

```
$startDate = new DateTime( '2013-04-01' );    //intialize start date
$endDate = new DateTime( '2013-04-30' );    //initialize end date
$holiday = array('2013-04-11','2013-04-25');  //this is assumed list of holiday
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');    // set the interval as 1 day
$daterange = new DatePeriod($startDate, $interval ,$endDate);
foreach($daterange as $date){
if($date->format("N") <6 AND !in_array($date->format("Y-m-d"),$holiday))
$result[] = $date->format("Y-m-d");
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($result);
```

A detail blog is here: http://goo.gl/YOsfPX